# Any text printing application that doesn't interpret the text at all?

Tags: linux

Is there any Linux application that just prints whatever you give it WITHOUT doing ANY sort of interpretation? So regardless of what I send to it, it would always output exactly what I send to it?

I want something with the functionality of `echo` or `printf`, but without interpreting the `\` and everything else.

Here's the kind of application I want:

```
newcommand "sa"" '' " "' ''""d f\sad\ f\sad\ \df\\ h\df\\\\\ sdf\h\sdfh\"" """" ''" " "ds\f\\\\ $%% \\as\ fsa\dg\ \afd\g\ \df\g \\df\g\\\\ n\ \n \\ sa\d \as \t a fsad g"" DF"G ""SD"F"" "DF"SG" """"Ds f"G" 'dsf'g 'sdf" G'ds f'g"SD fG"sd'f'g 'SFD""" ' > testfile1
cat testfile1
"sa"" '' " "' ''""d f\sad\ f\sad\ \df\\ h\df\\\\\ sdf\h\sdfh\"" """" ''" " "ds\f\\\\ $%% \\as\ fsa\dg\ \afd\g\ \df\g \\df\g\\\\ n\ \n \\ sa\d \as \t a fsad g"" DF"G ""SD"F"" "DF"SG" """"Ds f"G" 'dsf'g 'sdf" G'ds f'g"SD fG"sd'f'g 'SFD""" '
```

I can't find any program with this functionality. Basically, every positional parameter is outputted as is, including `"` and `'`. The only things that aren't outputted as-is would be `|<>` for obvious reasons

Okay, here's an even better example of what I want:

I want something that does, in command line and in one single line, something that can be achieved using `nano` or `vi` and writing one full line of text.

Comment: For context, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470303/ .  Observe that in two of the answers `printf` is indeed outputting exactly what it is given, and `\t` comes out as `\ ` followed by `t`.

Comment: That's not helping. Also this is for something else.

Comment: If you don't say why it's not helping we don't know in what direction you want to head instead.

Comment: Then, given that you already have `printf` doing what you say that you want, and contradicting the question's premise that `printf` is not doing, you have not adequately expressed your question.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude or anything, but the title is pretty clear: I need a Linux application that does exactly what I wrote, print the text without any interpretation. All of the comments and answers are about using other applications and using escapes. That's NOT what the question is about...
@JdeBP `printf` also interprets the strings you give it. I want something simple that never interprets anything. If you pass something to id, whatever it is, it would just output it back the same way you gave it, which then you can redirect. Basically, the functionality of echo without interprets.

Comment: You _have_ that in `printf`.  You even have several examples in answers of it _doing exactly that_, printing out its arguments with `%s`.  The problem is indeed that your question is _not_ clear, and an inadequate explanation of what you are asking for.

Comment: @JdeBP no, `printf` does NOT do what I asked. If it requires `%s` to do it, then it does NOT do what I ask. `%s` is `printf` INTERPRETING `%s` as something other than plain `%s`. What is my question? A program that DOESN'T interpret ANYTHING.
Seriously, my question is not that hard!

Comment: No-one said that it was hard.  We said that it was based upon an erroneous premise, unclear, and given that you reject the very thing that does what the question said that you wanted not adequately explaining what you wanted.   And demonstrably so, given that it now reads differently.  It now shows that you need to read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412823/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307011/ .

Comment: Stephane's answer basically cleared it to me. So the answer is that what I wanted is basically impossible because of shell restrictions.

Comment: How do you want to indicate the end of the text?

Comment: Why would an application that "doesn't interpret the text at all" behave any differently with `|<>` as input?  How are you providing the input to this program? As arguments, or as stdin?

Comment: `cat` is an application that doesn't interpret the text at all. If you want something like `echo` that outputs everything behind the `echo` unmodified, that's impossible. For details, look up how the shell processes command lines.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because I can't understand why what seem to be perfectly valid answers are all being rejected as unacceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those `"`, `\` are part of the shell syntax, they are not something that is passed to the command, the command cannot do anything about those.

The

```
printf %s 'foo " bar' "bar ' baz" > file
```

command line is code in the `sh` language (where the space, `'`, `"`, `>` characters have a specific meaning), it's not a line that it passes to the `printf` utility.

That's interpreted by the shell to run `printf` with `%s`, `foo " bar` and `bar ' baz` as arguments and its stdout redirected to `file`.

All `printf` sees is that list of arguments, it doesn't see the shell code (or python code if `printf` was called from python rather than a shell) that was used for it to be called with that list of arguments. `printf %s` will print each of those without doing any interpretation which will result in `file` containing `foo " barbar ' baz`.

Here you could use another shell syntax construct: the here-document, where the here-document delimiter is quoted, in which case, no interpretation is done:

```
cat << 'EOF' > testfile
"sa"" '' " "' ''""d f\sad\ f\sad\ \df\\ h\df\\\\\ sdf\h\sdfh\"" """" ''" " "ds\f\\\\ $%% \\as\ fsa\dg\ \afd\g\ \df\g \\df\g\\\\ n\ \n \\ sa\d \as \t a fsad g"" DF"G ""SD"F"" "DF"SG" """"Ds f"G" 'dsf'g 'sdf" G'ds f'g"SD fG"sd'f'g 'SFD""" '
EOF
```

The only restrictions on the text are:

- except with `zsh`, it can't contain NUL bytes
- it can't contain `EOF` on its own line (you can use a different delimiter if need be)
- except when the text is empty, there will always be a trailing newline character added.

Or you could run:

```
cat > file
```

After which it's `cat` and no longer the shell that will take your user input, then you can enter the content as you wish and end with <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.

As a hack, you could rely on the fact that shells don't do any interpretation of text in comment and retrieve the command line from the saved history and output what's past the `#`. For instance, with the `bash` shell, interactively:

```
fc -l -0 | cut -d '#' -f3- > testfile #the text here with \ ' "
```

Comment: Thank you. So basically, there is no way any command would be able to redirect text as-is into a file, the same way you would just write it with `vi` or `nano`?

Comment: @iamAguest, I think you misunderstand what a shell command line is. See if the edit makes it any clearer.

Comment: Thanks, that's really the best answer here, but the only problem here is that I cannot do all that in just one line of text, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: @iamAguest, see edit for a hacky way.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not a Linux-specific application, but [`cat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html) does just that when run without arguments: it copies its standard input to its standard output, with no change.

Comment: I cannot redirect it to a file though. I want something with the functionality of `echo` or `printf`, but without interpreting the \ and everything else.

Comment: @iamAguest Use `cat` with a quoted here-document redirected into the file you want to write to.